# Retrieve disk usage on home dir & vmail with Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash

Here I am, new and wet behind the ears to Bash/Shell Scripting.

Basically I am needing to know how to utilize sed in this instance on one of two very basic scripts. The intention is to retrieve disk usage info based on username/domain name.

You might be asking why two of the same scripts?

Given I work with many username/domains, the default domain_usage will be be overwritten into to domain_usage_tmp as and when username/domain changes. I have tried using sed to substitute, which has not provided the intended results:

```bash
sed 's/username/x/g' 's/domain/x/g' /scripts/domain_usage_tmp
```

Provide me with knowledge and wisdom :-)

Comment: Use `sed -i` to edit files in-place.  Also, what is the output you get versus what you expect, or error?

Comment: So what is the format of `domain_usage_tmp`? Please post a few lines and explain the format.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forget to use the `-i` option:

```
man sed
...
       -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

              edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

```
sed -i 's/username/x/g' 's/domain/x/g' /scripts/domain_usage_tmp
```